# Grails 4-IntelliJ IDEA version 19 increased compilation time

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, intellij-14, grails-controller, intellij-19

We are using IntelliJ IDEA version 19 towards development of a web application in Grails 4 framework. The issue we are facing is, while undertaking code changes in controller, services and domain the IntelliJ IDEA version 19 is compiling the entire project, i.e. the project gets restarted and the entire project gets complied from the beginning as a result of which the whole process of compilation is taking longer time. Where else compilation of GSP and JavaScript files are happening dynamically without restarting the entire project.

It is requested the way ahead for the said issue to be provided.

Comment: What's your question and what was your current approach to mitigate the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.